# Exchange li's elements from each other

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to exchange elements between two ul.

The first movement which I change the position it's ok, but when I try to do it in reverse, it doesn't work and I don't know why, could someone help me please?

Thanks.

My code:

```
<form action="php/paso_1.php" name="marcas" method="post">          
    <ul class="lista original">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="marca" value="farola"/><a href="#">farola</a></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="marca" value="zapato"/> <a href="#">Zapato</a></li>        
        <input class="boton dos" type="submit" value="Ok"/>
    </ul>   
    <div class="slide">
            <a class="toggle" href="#">Ver Seleccionados</a>

            <ul class="elegidos anade"> 

            </ul>
        </div>
 </form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.original li').on('click',clonaCol);
$('.anade li').on('click',desselec);


function clonaCol(e){
$('.anade').append($(this));
$('.anade input').prop('checked','checked');
e.preventDefault();}

function desselec(e){
$('.original').append($(this));
e.preventDefault;}
```

Comment: Use boolean values when you use `.prop()` for checking a checkbox so `.prop('checked',true)`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `input` directly in `ul` without a `li`.

Comment: but, the input which isn't in a ul, is the submit, does it needs to be on a li too? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoul bind the click another time.
This is because the elements after the first shift need a new bind of the click event

working example

http://jsfiddle.net/2K5qR/

javascript

```
$('.original li').on('click',clonaCol);
$('.anade li').on('click',desselec);


function clonaCol(e){
$('.anade').append($(this));
$(this).on('click',desselec); 
$('.anade input').prop('checked','checked');
e.preventDefault();}

function desselec(e){
$('.original').append($(this));
    $(this).on('click',clonaCol); 
e.preventDefault;}
```

html is the same of your

Comment: @laura133 mark whatever answer helps you best as 'accepted' so that this question doesn't show up as 'unanswered'. thanks